# BASH - run concated variable with alias as command

Tags: bash, variables, command, csh

I have an text-file script in `#!/bin/bash`, where I run concated variable CMD as command and it works in Csh, but not in Bash.

```
CMD="word${year} ${FILE_version.txt} > ${FILE_version.out} &"
(CMD='word'"$year"' '"$FILE_version.txt"' > '"$FILE_version.out"' &'
```

I also tried this second version of CMD variable, it didnt help)

- `word2018` - alias defined/sourced default from other location
  (single alias `word2018` works OK in bash shell terminal)
- `word` - static text name
- `2018` - variable (can be any year number `2015`, `2018`, `2022`,....)
- `FILE_version` - variable (can be - `FILE_2015`, `FILE_2018`, `FILE_2022`,...)

The command

```
csh -c "$CMD"
```

works OK in a Bash shell terminal, but

```
bash -c "$CMD"
```

is NOT working in bash shell terminal, I get  `word2018 - command not found`

Comment: Variables are for data, not code. Define a function instead. Also, be sure to read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Any other errors aside, you shouldn't expect to be able to pass the same string to `csh -c` and `bash -c`; `csh` and `bash` are two very different languages.

Comment: Aliases are not expanded in non-interactive shells. This is by no means the only reason to avoid aliases, but a crucial one in this case.